# How to align an even number of items horizontally with spacing between the items using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with dynamically aligning some items using Bootstrap when there are an even number of items.

I have 4 HTML `select` items next to each other and I want to have some spacing between them. Therefore I have set every select item in a `col-md-3 div`. For that I have used width 80% for each of them. Below these I have a `table` which I want to have size 100%. I have placed all items in a `row` container. I want the selectors to align up with the table below which I can not manage to do.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;">
        <label>Test1</label>
        <select style="width: 80%">
            <option selected="selected" value="1">Test1</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;">
        <label>Test2</label>
        <select style="width: 80%">
            <option selected="selected" value="1">Test2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;">
        <label>Test3</label>
        <select style="width: 80%">
            <option selected="selected" value="1">Test3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;">
        <label>Test4</label>
        <select style="width: 80%">
            <option selected="selected" value="1">Test4</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <p>
       Some description
    </p>

    <table class="text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <th>2</th>
                <th>3</th>
                <th>4</th>
                <th>5</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that since I use 80% width on the selectors the last selector, i.e. "Test5" does not align up with the end border of the table. I think the problem is clear if one looks at the the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dolle39/2m9t0n4u/6/).

So how can one dynamically align items with Bootstrap and have spacing between the elements? I have attached an image below with the desired design, how I want it to look.

[image: Desired design.]

Comment: If only "Test4" aligns with the end of the table it will look weird because none of the others do that.

Comment: Based on the code you are using everything aligns correctly. Seems like you need to make a design decision on how you want the select boxes to show.

Comment: Bootstrap columns are divided into 12 col layout. If you want to align 5 which is an odd number columns of a table with default Bootstrap col class then either you need to use table which will have columns divisible by 2 or change default col class into custom class.

Comment: @Debraj: Yes I know that  but I am not trying to align with 5, I am trying to align 4 selectors. It could equally well have been an image or a line instead of a table. I have 4 selectors which I want to place out as the image shows.

Comment: When you applying `col-md-3` or similar you are telling Bootstrap to divide each column into `4` equal sections. And you have `5` columns in below which is equally divided into by `5`. So, you need to either add a spacer to top column to fill the gap or make both `even`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what your looking? https://jsfiddle.net/fjavmgrf/1/

If you take away the padding I personally think it looks better, but you have that option open to you.

```
select{
  width:100%;
}

.paddingZero{
  padding:0;
}
```

Or this: https://jsfiddle.net/37z2dqqk/1

**EDIT (After image was put up:**

What you want isn't really possible with bootstrap. Yes you could play about with the padding and possibly the margins and hack it but I'm personally not a fan of it. If you do still want to do it that way then basically just adjust the padding until it works and keep the select at 100%. Sorry I can't be of my help but my honest advice would be to go with one of the suggestions in my answers or those in the comments above as well.

Comment: Not quite but almost. I want to have padding beteen selector Test1 and Test2, Test2 and Test3 and finally Test3 and Test4. But then I also want the edge of the outer selectors to align with the table. I want the padding to be symmetric.

Comment: If you take away the padding I added in my fiddle example it centers all the text boxes and has the same amount of padding around them (due to the columns default padding). Unless you do that or keep them at 0 padding it's going to look quite off in my opinion. You'll have two text boxes left aligned and two right aligned or something like that. Could you draw me an image of what you want and post it in the question?

Comment: That is almost what I want. I have modified the question and added a image to make the desired design more clear. As you can see I still want to have same size of all selectors but with even spacing between them. I added one more column to the table to make it clear that the selectors should not align up with the cells which I think made things confusing.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. What you want isn't really possible with bootstrap. Yes you could play about with the padding and possibly the margins and hack it but I'm personally not a fan of it. If you do still want to do it that way then basically just adjust the padding until it works and keep the select at 100%. Sorry I can't be of my help but my honest advice would be to go with one of the suggestions in my answers or those in the comments above as well.

Comment: Okey thanks. I started to get that feeling from the other comments as well. Please write this as an answer so I can accept that as the correct one.

Comment: Cheers mate. I've edited the answer to what will hopefully make sense to someone who stumbles across this thread in the future. I'm happy to see you've kinda found your answer, this is why SO is so great, it either validates your ideas or points you in a slightly different direction (or make you think about something in a totally different way).